# In a function, ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Tags: python

I have a function:

```
def load_data(datafile, categories=None, cat_columns=None):
  # Some stuff
  return (data_x, data_y, categorical_columns) + ((ohe.categories_, ) if not categories else ())
```

I am then calling it twice with:

```
training_x, training_y, cat_columns, categories = loader.load_data(
    'data/training.csv')

test_x, test_y = loader.load_data(
    'data/test.csv', categories=categories, cat_columns=cat_columns)
```

Then I get the dreaded `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)` error, specifically for the second time I'm calling it (test_x, test_y)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your second call fails, because you expect 2 but the function returns 3 or 4 depending on condition.

Comment: For the second line, `training_x, training_y, cat_columns = loader.load_data(…)`

Comment: Having a function that sometimes returns 3 values and other times returns 4 seems like a recipe for disaster.

Comment: But either way, you can't assign the result to only two variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
x,y = [1,2,3] # x=1, y=2 but we didn't have any variable to store element 3
```

the above written line will produce an **ValueError : too many values to unpack**.

As here we are trying to unpack the list element and assign them to variable but we have three element in list to unpack and only two variable to store the value, to solve this we have to provide one more variable.

```
x,y,z = [1,2,3] # here we have x=1, y=2, z=3
```

Answer (score 1):

`if not categories else ()`
If categories, you're returning an empty tuple. At best, that's only one value. You can't unpack an empty tuple into two values, `test_x, test_y`.

I'm not sure what you want to do here, but you could fix it by having it

```py
return ... if not categories else (None, None)
```

Comment: Actually, it's returning either a 3-tuple or 4-tuple depending on the result of the `if`. Check the `+` and parentheses.

Comment: Oh, that's true, I miscounted the parentheses. Either way it's the wrong number of things.